# recursive java reinitalize list to be empty

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I am querying a tree looking for nodes with the data string "directory" and then reporting its children's data in a list.

At the start of my method, I have initalized my list like so.
List listofdirectories = new ArrayList<>();

While debugging, java does recursively go through the tree and ADD the strings to the list, but once it calls itself again, the listofdirectories variable becomes empty again during the recursion. However, at the end, it puts out a list of the root directory and its directory children.

My method takes in no parameters. Posted code on pastebin, theres a lot of System.outs for me to debug with.

My method's code + the console + an example tree is posted here:
https://pastebin.com/9nXvcCNS

```
public List<String> getDirectories() // WORKS b/c didnt add first directory
        {
                List<String> listofdirectories = new ArrayList<>();
                System.out.println("AT THE START OF THE METHOD " +listofdirectories);
               // int sizeofchildrennodes = this.children.size();
               
                if(this.data.equals("directory"))
                {
                    System.out.println("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF");
                }
               
                if(this.data.equals(("directory")))
                {
                    listofdirectories.add(this.children.get(0).children.get(0).data);
                   
                for (int i = 0; i < this.children.size(); i++) { // Checks the directories in the CURRENT directory
               
                    String nodename = this.children.get(i).data;              
                    FileSystemNode thenode = this.children.get(i);
                   
                    System.out.println("Current node is: " + nodename);
                    System.out.println("Current nodedata is: " + thenode.children.get(0).data);
                   
                  if(nodename.equals("directory2.0"))
                {
                    System.out.println("I found direct2.0");
                    System.out.println("name of direct2.0 is " + thenode.children.get(0).children.get(0).data);
                    System.out.println("0" + listofdirectories);
                    listofdirectories.add(thenode.children.get(0).children.get(0).data);
                    System.out.println("0).5" +listofdirectories);
                }
                 
                    System.out.println("1" +listofdirectories);
                   
                if(nodename.equals("directory"))
                {
                    System.out.println("@@" + listofdirectories);
                    listofdirectories.add(thenode.children.get(0).children.get(0).data);
                    if(thenode.children.size()> 0)
                    {
                        thenode.getDirectories();
                    }
                   
                }
               
                }
//                if(this.children.get(i).children.contains(i))
               
            }
                System.out.println("!!!beforeoutput" +listofdirectories);
                return listofdirectories;
        }


//////////////////////////////////
/// This is console's log
////////////////////////////////////
AT THE START OF THE METHOD []
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Current node is: name
Current nodedata is: Movies and Pictures
1[Movies and Pictures]
Current node is: directory
Current nodedata is: name
1[Movies and Pictures]
@@[Movies and Pictures]
AT THE START OF THE METHOD []
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Current node is: name
Current nodedata is: Movies
1[Movies]
Current node is: file
Current nodedata is: name
1[Movies]
Current node is: file
Current nodedata is: name
1[Movies]
Current node is: file
Current nodedata is: name
1[Movies]
!!!beforeoutput[Movies]
Current node is: directory
Current nodedata is: name
1[Movies and Pictures, Movies]
@@[Movies and Pictures, Movies]
AT THE START OF THE METHOD []
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
Current node is: name
Current nodedata is: Pictures
1[Pictures]
Current node is: file
Current nodedata is: name
1[Pictures]
Current node is: file
Current nodedata is: name
1[Pictures]
Current node is: file
Current nodedata is: name
1[Pictures]
Current node is: directory2.0
Current nodedata is: name
I found direct2.0
name of direct2.0 is Pictures2.0
0[Pictures]
0).5[Pictures, Pictures2.0]
1[Pictures, Pictures2.0]
!!!beforeoutput[Pictures, Pictures2.0]
!!!beforeoutput[Movies and Pictures, Movies, Pictures]
2 [Movies and Pictures, Movies, Pictures] // THIS IS THE OUTPUT
//I WANT THIS TO INCLUDE PICTURES2.0

///////////////////////
//// Example of a tree
//////////////////////

|-- directory
    |-- name
        |-- Movies and Pictures
    |-- directory
        |-- name
            |-- Movies
        |-- file
            |-- name
                |-- Harry Potter.mov
            |-- date
                |-- 20130602
            |-- size
                |-- 1400123
        |-- file
            |-- name
                |-- Dodgeball.avi
            |-- date
                |-- 11111111
            |-- size
                |-- 5000000
        |-- file
            |-- name
                |-- The Dark Knight.mpeg
            |-- date
                |-- 55555555
            |-- size
                |-- 7657657
    |-- directory
        |-- name
            |-- Pictures
        |-- file
            |-- name
                |-- Mountain.png
            |-- date
                |-- 20000000
            |-- size
                |-- 190000
        |-- file
            |-- name
                |-- Flower.jpg
            |-- date
                |-- 140000
            |-- size
                |-- 7657657
        |-- file
            |-- name
                |-- Wildlife.jpeg
            |-- date
                |-- 90000000
            |-- size
                |-- 250000
        |-- directory2.0
            |-- name
                |-- Pictures2.0
```

---

#### Solved

The solution to an example tree query is here: https://pastebin.com/FkBTatP6

Comment: Please do not use test code when you post a question, it is not useful and it makes your code more difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing anything with the return value. Look here:

```
thenode.getDirectories();
```

Ok, you have called the method, but what do you do with its return value set? Nothing. You are not storing it. So, why do you expect your code to return the correct set if you are not storing it? I think this should get you closer to the solution of your problem instead:

```
listofdirectories.addAll(thenode.getDirectories());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> listofdirectories = new ArrayList<>();
```

declare in globel scope.

Comment: I put List<String> listofdirectories = new ArrayList<>(); outside of the method. Returns the same output.

Comment: are you remove these line in methods.

Comment: Yes I did. I just cut it out of the method.

Comment: It is exactly the same as the other console comments. Oddly enough.